# display All Tables in a single row in new table

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server I wrote a query to count specific columns but I am displaying all count in more than one table, it's not a good way to show. How to display all tables in single row in new table?

```
     select COUNT(s.AssetSubType) as 'PhysicalServers' from Asset s
      where s.CompanyId = @companyId and
            s.AssetType = 1 and
            s.AssetSubType = 4 

   select COUNT(s.AssetSubType) as 'WorkStations' from Asset s
      where s.CompanyId = @companyId and
            s.AssetType = 1 and
            s.AssetSubType = 1 or s.AssetSubType = 3    

 select COUNT(s.AssetSubType) as 'EmailOnlyUsers' from Asset s
      where s.CompanyId = @companyId and
            s.AssetType = 2 and 
            s.AssetSubType = 16             

 select COUNT(s.OperatingSystem) as '#OfMSServers' from Asset s
      where s.CompanyId = @companyId and
            s.AssetType = 1 and
            s.AssetSubType = 4 and 
            s.OperatingSystem = 1 

 select COUNT(s.OperatingSystem) as '#OfLinuxServers' from Asset s
      where s.CompanyId = @companyId and
            s.AssetType = 1 and
            s.AssetSubType = 4 and 
            s.OperatingSystem = 2
```

Comment: As an aside, are you aware that the condition in your second query will match rows with `s.AssetSubType = 3` and **any** `s.AssetType` and **any** `s.CompanyId`? Did you by any chance mean this: `s.CompanyId = @companyId and s.AssetType = 1 and (s.AssetSubType = 1 or s.AssetSubType = 3)` (brackets around the disjunction)?

Comment: Still better would be to replace the disjunction with `… in (1, 3)`, like this: `s.CompanyId = @companyId and s.AssetType = 1 and s.AssetSubType in (1, 3)`.

Comment: How we can write below expression  in better way s.AssetSubType <> 1 and s.AssetSubType <> 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you

```
select sum(case when s.AssetType = 1 and 
                     s.AssetSubType = 4 
                then 1 end) as 'PhysicalServers',
       sum(case when s.AssetType = 1 and 
                     (s.AssetSubType = 1 or s.AssetSubType = 3) 
                then 1 end) as 'WorkStations',
       sum(case when s.AssetType = 2 and 
                     s.AssetSubType = 16 
                then 1 end) as 'EmailOnlyUsers',
       sum(case when s.AssetType = 1 and 
                     s.AssetSubType = 4 and 
                     s.OperatingSystem = 1 
                then 1 end) as '#OfMSServers',
       sum(case when s.AssetType = 1 and 
                     s.AssetSubType = 4 and 
                     s.OperatingSystem = 2 
                then 1 end) as '#OfLinuxServers'
from Asset s
where s.CompanyId = @companyId
```

Comment: @AndriyM - Yes but by the looks of it the columns that are counted is also part of the where clause so there should be no nulls, right? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Thanks Mikael. But  what is "then 1"

Comment: @IndraRamasani It's a part of the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement. Instead of counting I am summing all the "ones" where the expression is true. If the expression is false the value from the case is `null` and will not be summed.

Comment: The `1` is needed. If that is what you mean. It is the `else` in the that is not needed but could be included for completeness. `sum case when SomeExpr=12 then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: How we can write below expression in better way s.AssetSubType <> 1 and s.AssetSubType <> 3

Comment: @IndraRamasani How is that a bad way? You could write it differently `s.AssetSubType not in (1, 3)` not necessarily better.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed column "serverType" which have a unique value for each config type:

```
ALTER TABLE [Asset]
 ADD [serverType] AS (
    CASE 
     WHEN (AssetType = 1 and AssetSubType = 4) THEN 'PhysicalServers'
     WHEN (AssetType = 1 and AssetSubType = 1 AssetSubType = 3) THEN 'WorkStations'
     [etc..]
     ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
)
```

Then you can simply query

```
SELECT COUNT(s.OperatingSystem) FROM Asset s
WHERE s.CompanyId = @companyId 
GROUP BY serverType
```

Comment: Main interest of this method is that your SP (or query) will never change. You can then simply add/modify server type just in the definition of your computed column.